# Тормоза приложения на Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: android

Написал приложение, возникла проблема: появилась жалоба пользователя Samsung Galaxy s4 - приложение тормозит (анимация, списки, все...).

У меня три девайса:

- lenovo (android 4.2)
- fly (android 4.1)
- highscreen (android 4.4)

На них все хорошо работает, но к сожалению Galaxy s4 нет. Покупать каждый девайс плохой вариант. Как проверить фунциональности приложения на этот девайс? Может ли кто проверить, вдруг проблема с конкретным телефоном?

Comment: у меня когда то были тормоза на некоторых телефонах из-за того что в `GridView` были картинки большого размера(ну как большого, такого се). В общем после поправки этого бага, все заработало нормально

Answer (score 1):

В jenymotion есть список виртуальных девайсов, Galaxy s4 есть в списку, попробуй скачать и протестировать. Вот ссылка:
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/